# $W = \{ \alpha \in \mathbf{R}^n | \alpha' A \alpha = 0\}$ doesn't have a subspace of more than $n-p+1$ dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $A$ is a full rank symmetric matrix of real numbers $R$, prove that :

$W = \{ \alpha \in \mathbf{R}^n | \alpha' A \alpha = 0\}$ doesn't have a subspace of more than $n-p+1$ dimensions($p$ is the positive index of inertia).

Considering that $A$ is symmetric we can get an invertible matrix $C$ such that

$CAC' = \mathbf{diag}\{1,\cdots,1, -1,\cdots, -1\}$

where there are $p$ "$1$"s and $n-p$ "$-1$"s. So we can just consider the diagonal matrices.

But then I don't how to continue.

Comment: The question is a little odd to me: do you have to prove that $\;W\;$ doesn't have a subspace of more that...etc., or that $\;\dim W\le n-p+1\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio $W$ is in fact not a vector space and I just want to prove that a subset of $W$ which is a space of dimensions...etc. doesn't exist.

Comment: From your comment I gather that $\;\alpha=\alpha^t\;$ and thus $\;W\;$ is the set of zeros of a quadratic form...is this correct?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes and I gonna go to bed now so maybe I can’t answer in time later